# Access resources in Fragment constructor

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a `Fragment` and in the empty constructor I need to be able to access string resources so I can create construct components of the fragment.

I am aware that I should probably use `newInstance()` instead of constructors but constructors have been working so far and it seemed like a lot of hassle to pass custom objects using `Bundle`.

My fragment constructor is as follows:

```
public SideMenuView(Context ctx) {

    menuItems = new MenuItem[] {

            new MenuItem(R.drawable.one_icon, ctx.getResources().getString(R.string.one), R.id.imgChevron),
            new MenuItem(R.drawable.two_icon, ctx.getResources().getString(R.string.two), R.id.imgChevron),
            new MenuItem(R.drawable.three_icon, ctx.getResources().getString(R.string.three), R.id.imgChevron)
        };

    fragCache = new Fragment[menuItems.length];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need to get these resources in the constructor? I would just move that piece of code to the `onCreate()` method.

Comment: That's exactly what I did after posting this question, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

to use menu inside fragment it's enough to:

a) add following method that build menu from XML resource

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater)
{
     inflater.inflate(R.menu.attendance_fragment, menu);
}
```

b) add

```
setHasOptionsMenu(true);
```

in fragment constructor to hint android that your fragment wants to participate in populating the options menu

Comment: Hi, while this is a menu it's not an options menu like normal. Its com.slidingmenu from jfeinstein. Thanks.